# I cannot retrieve and view data from Firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

**#HOME: this is home linked to FeatureProducts()**

And I cannot retrieve data "product", it always return nil.

I want to retrieve data from Firebase into the Listview.

this is my firebase cloud fire store Image of Firebase Database

i try many time with many ways and all codes doesn't give any errors, but When i run the app and open the activity the data cannot show they will be empty,

```
import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/commons/common.dart';

import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/db/product.dart';

import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/pages/product_search.dart';
import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/provider/product.dart';
import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/provider/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/widget/featured_products.dart';
import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/widget/product_card.dart';
import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/widgets/custom_text.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'cart.dart';
import 'order.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
 }

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
final _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
ProductServices _productServices = ProductServices();


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
final productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);

return Scaffold(
  key: _key,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  endDrawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
          accountName: CustomText(
            text: userProvider.userModel?.name ?? "username lading...",
            color: Colors.white,
            weight: FontWeight.bold,
            size: 18,
          ),
          accountEmail: CustomText(
            text: userProvider.userModel?.email ?? "email loading...",
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          onTap: () async{
            await userProvider.getOrders();
            changeScreen(context, OrdersScreen());
          },
          leading: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
          title: CustomText(text: "My orders"),
        ),

        ListTile(
          onTap: () async{
           userProvider.signOut();
          },

        leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),

        title: CustomText(text: "Log out"),
          ),
          ],
         ),
        ),

       body: SafeArea(
       child: ListView(
       children: <Widget>[
       //         Custom App bar

       Stack(
       children: <Widget>[

            Positioned(
              top: 10,
              right: 20,
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _key.currentState.openEndDrawer();
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.menu))),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 10,
              right: 60,
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        changeScreen(context, CartScreen());
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart))),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 10,
              right: 100,
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight, child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    _key.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text("User profile")));
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.person))),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'What are\nyou Shopping for?',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),

        //          Search Text field
        //            Search(),

        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20))),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 8, left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 10),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                title: TextField(
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                  onSubmitted: (pattern)async{
                    await productProvider.search(productName: pattern);
                    changeScreen(context, ProductSearchScreen());
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "fashion....",
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //            featured products
        Row(
        children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
              child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: new Text('Featured products')),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        FeaturedProducts(), 
 **this is the feature products. i cannot see any thing on here. 
         its blank**

        //          recent products
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
              child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: new Text('Recent products')),
            ),
          ],
        ),

        Column(
          children: productProvider.products
              .map((item) => GestureDetector(
            child: ProductCard(
              product: item,
            ),
          ))
              .toList(),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
  }
  }
```

**#FEATURED PRODUCT: this is linked to ProductProvider which listens from the
database**

```
     import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/provider/product.dart';
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

     import 'featured_card.dart';

     class FeaturedProducts extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     _FeaturedProductsState createState() => _FeaturedProductsState();
     }

    class _FeaturedProductsState extends State<FeaturedProducts> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);

    return Container(
    height: 230,
    child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: productProvider.products.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return FeaturedCard(
            product: productProvider.products[index],
          );
        }));
      }
      }
```

**#PRODUCT PROVIDER**
//i feel the provider is not loading any products

```
      import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/db/product.dart';

      import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/models/product.dart';

      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

   class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier{
   ProductServices _productServices = ProductServices();
   List<ProductModel> products = [];
   List<ProductModel> productsSearched = [];


   ProductProvider.initialize(){
   loadProducts();
   }

   loadProducts()async{enter code here
   products = await _productServices.getProducts();
   notifyListeners();
  }

 Future search({String productName})async{
 productsSearched = await _productServices.searchProducts(productName: productName);
 notifyListeners();
 }

 }
```

**//DATABASE TO FIRESTORE**
//I tried using stream builder but it is not working using Future.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:farmers_ecommerce/models/product.dart';


class ProductServices {
String collection = "products";
FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

Future<List<ProductModel>> getProducts() async =>
  _firestore.collection(collection).get().then((result) {
    List<ProductModel> products = [];
    for (DocumentSnapshot product in result.docs) {
      products.add(ProductModel.fromSnapshot(product));
    }
    return products;
  });

 Future<List<ProductModel>> searchProducts({String productName}) {
// code to convert the first character to uppercase
String searchKey = productName[0].toUpperCase() + productName.substring(1);
return _firestore
    .collection(collection).  //return fire base
    .orderBy("name")
    .startAt([searchKey])
    .endAt([searchKey + '\uf8ff'])
    .get()
    .then((result) {
  List<ProductModel> products = [];
  for (DocumentSnapshot product in result.docs) {
    products.add(ProductModel.fromSnapshot(product));
  }
  return products;
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ProductServices` change this function:

```dart
Future<List<ProductModel>> getProducts() async {
      QuerySnapshot result= await _firestore.collection(collection).get();
      List<ProductModel> products = [];
      for (DocumentSnapshot product in result.docs) {
        products.add(ProductModel.fromSnapshot(product));
      }
      return products;
}
```

If you use `then` the `return` will be called when the code flow already left the function. To avoid that you need to `await` the result.

Comment: Can you pls log the value of `products` before they are returned and check if there is something inside.